# Run Mysql scripts in a batch?

Tags: sql, mysql

Can someone link me to a tutorial or explain if there is a way to create some sort of batch file of mysql scripts / stored procs and run them all at the same time? I can not seem to find any documentation on this online but I feel that I might be searching using the wrong terms.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply create a text file with SQL statements separated with ; and then execute all statements with the MySQL command line client:

```
# my_textfile.sql
# ---------------
USE my_database;
SELECT * FROM table1;
UPDATE table2 SET foo='bar';

Command Line:
mysql < my_textfile.sql
```

Answer (score 7):

You can chain mysql scripts by calling them from within a script using the source command ([details of command line options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html))

```
# my_textfile.sql
# ---------------
USE my_database;
\. subscript1.sql
\. subdir/subscript2.sql
\. /full/path/to/subscript3.sql

Command Line:
mysql < my_textfile.sql
```

Don't forget the command line options, if you are going to script the files you might need the password/ user account.

```
mysql -uyouraccount -pyourpassword YourDatabase < mytextfile.sql
```

This isn't the most secure way to do it because it puts your username/ password on the command line but it works.  If you are doing much scripting I suggest you look into [.my.cnf](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) and the various options for saving your account/ password in there (and securing that file).

Comment: Just wanted to note that I did steal a bit of sample code from Tomas if it isn't obvious.

Answer (score 1):

For peeps running MAMP PRO on OS X Yosemite, I was able to get all my *.sql scripts executed (import) by running from terminal:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -h localhost -u root -p < /Applications/MAMP/myDBRestore.sql
```

`myDBRestore.sql` contained a reference to all the MySQL DB scripts as thus:

```
\. /full/path/to/sql/file1.sql
\. /full/path/to/sql/file2.sql
\. /full/path/to/sql/file3.sql
...
\. /full/path/to/sql/file(n).sql
```

where `n` is the last `.sql` file in the directory.